# Abrir apenas a modal clicada?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, react, react-hooks

Eu tenho um `map` de um `array` de objetos.

```
<S.Section>
    {data.slice(oldItems, showItems).map((it, index) => {
      return (
        <>
          <S.Box key={index} onClick={openDetails}>
            <S.Image src={it.picture.large} />
            <S.Gender>{it.gender === "male" ? "Masculino" : "Feminino"}</S.Gender>
            <S.Name>
              {it.name.title} {it.name.first} {it.name.last}
            </S.Name>
            <S.Email>{it.email}</S.Email>
          </S.Box>
          {openInfo && (
            <Details data={it} toggleModal={openDetails} />
          )}
        </>
      );
    })}
</S.Section>
```

***Eu queria que***: ao clicar em um Box, ele abrisse apenas a modal com as informações da Box clicada. O problema: Todas as Box que estão no `map` atual, ao clicar em qualquer uma estão sendo abertas. Acredito que o problema está no referenciamento do `data={it}` pois o `it` possui todos os objetos do `map` e eu não consigo diferenciá-los, por não ter um ID vindo da `api`.

Um dos objetos vindo da `api` (dados *fake*)

```
{
    "gender":"female",
    "name":{
        "title":"mrs",
        "first":"ione",
        "last":"da costa"
    },
    "location": {
      "street":"8614 avenida vinícius de morais",
      "city":"ponta grossa",
      "state":"rondônia",
      "postcode":97701,
      "coordinates":{
        "latitude":"-76.3253",
        "longitude":"137.9437"
      },
      "timezone":{
        "offset":"-1:00",
        "description":"Azores, Cape Verde Islands"
      }
    },
    "email":"ione.dacosta@example.com",
    "dob":{
      "date":"1968-01-24T18:03:23Z",
      "age":50
    },
    "registered":{
      "date":"2004-01-23T23:54:33Z",
      "age":14
    },
    "phone":"(01) 5415-5648",
    "cell":"(10) 8264-5550",
    "picture":{
      "large":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/46.jpg",
      "medium":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/46.jpg",
      "thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/46.jpg"
    }
}
```

Comment: Como está os objetos vindo da API? Poste-os também.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o objeto

Comment: Mesmo que a API não tenha especificamente um ID vc pode ver alguma informação que ela traga que não se repete e usar como o parametro key no map. Nesse caso acima eu acho que poderia ser o email, mas creio que essa API tem um campo chamado uuid que ficaria ótimo pra ser usado, só que no caso voce tem fazer com que sua aplicação retorne esse campo no fetch

Comment: Como é o método `openDetails`?

Comment: É:
const [openInfo, setOpenInfo] = useState(false);

 const openDetails = () => {
    setOpenInfo(!openInfo);
  }

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foi utilizado nesse exemplo o [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) para exibir o Modal, então o que eu faço tem uma variável que controlar quando vai ser exibido o modal (variável `show`) e tenho também outra variável para carregar as informações individual do item selecionado e clicado, não precisando saber qual é o item em uma pesquisa, já é forçado o seu valor dentro de um função com parâmetro.

Começa tudo pelo componente `<App />` e ao carregar os outro componente eu passo as variáveis e as funções para que os outros componentes compartilhem da mesma informação.

Exemplo minimo:

```js
function Modal({show, card, handleClose}) {
  var Modal = ReactBootstrap.Modal;
  var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
  return (
    <div>
      <Modal show={show}>
        <Modal.Header>
          {card && card.name.title}
          {' '}
          {card && card.name.first}
          {' '}
          {card && card.name.last}
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <div>{card && card.email}</div>
          <div>{card && card.location.street}</div>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                            Fechar
          </Button>                 
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </div> 
  )
}

function Card({card, handleOpenCard}) {
  return (
    <div class="card" style={{width: '18rem', margin: 10}}>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{card.name.first}</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">
        {card.email}
        </h6>
        <p class="card-text">a</p>
        <button class="btn btn-link" onClick={handleOpenCard}>
        Abrir
        </button>          
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState(data);
  const [card, setCard] = React.useState(null);
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpenCard = (card) => {      
    setCard(card);
    setShow(true);    
  }
  const handleClose = (e) => {    
    setShow(false);
    setCard(null);
  }
  return (
    <div>
    <Modal card={card} show={show} handleClose={handleClose} />
    {items.map((card, idx) => 
      (<Card idx={idx} 
        card={card} 
        handleOpenCard={e => handleOpenCard(card)}
       />
    ))}
    </div>
  )
}


const data = [{
  "gender": "male",
  "name": {
    "title": "mr",
    "first": "souza",
    "last": "da costa"
  },
  "location": {
    "street": "8614 avenida vinícius de morais",
    "city": "ponta grossa",
    "state": "rondônia",
    "postcode": 97701,
    "coordinates": {
      "latitude": "-76.3253",
      "longitude": "137.9437"
    },
    "timezone": {
      "offset": "-1:00",
      "description": "Azores, Cape Verde Islands"
    }
  },
  "email": "souza.mary@example.com",
  "dob": {
    "date": "1968-01-24T18:03:23Z",
    "age": 50
  },
  "registered": {
    "date": "2004-01-23T23:54:33Z",
    "age": 14
  },
  "phone": "(01) 5415-5648",
  "cell": "(10) 8264-5550",
  "picture": {
    "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/46.jpg",
    "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/46.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/46.jpg"
  }
}, {
  "gender": "female",
  "name": {
    "title": "mrs",
    "first": "ione",
    "last": "da costa"
  },
  "location": {
    "street": "8614 avenida vinícius de morais",
    "city": "ponta grossa",
    "state": "rondônia",
    "postcode": 97701,
    "coordinates": {
      "latitude": "-76.3253",
      "longitude": "137.9437"
    },
    "timezone": {
      "offset": "-1:00",
      "description": "Azores, Cape Verde Islands"
    }
  },
  "email": "ione.dacosta@example.com",
  "dob": {
    "date": "1968-01-24T18:03:23Z",
    "age": 50
  },
  "registered": {
    "date": "2004-01-23T23:54:33Z",
    "age": 14
  },
  "phone": "(01) 5415-5648",
  "cell": "(10) 8264-5550",
  "picture": {
    "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/46.jpg",
    "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/46.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/46.jpg"
  }
}];
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
  crossorigin></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```